# How to parse key value json with Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

I want to decode this JSON with Codable.
Without yellow highlighted, this solution worked but if highlighted section comes from server, codable not working.
Please help me.

[image]

**My solution is:**

```
    let others : [String: OthersType?]?



    enum OthersType: Codable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
    case bool(Bool)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        do {
            self = try .int(container.decode(Int.self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            do {
                self = try .string(container.decode(String.self))
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                do {
                    self = try .bool(container.decode(Bool.self))
                } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(OthersType.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Encoded payload not of an expected type"))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .int(let int):
            try container.encode(int)
        case .string(let string):
            try container.encode(string)
        case .bool(let bool):
            try container.encode(bool)
        }
    }

    func getValue(_ ofTheWord: OthersType) -> String {
        var result = String(describing: ofTheWord)
        if result.contains("string(") {
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "string(\"", with: "")
            result.removeLast(2)

        } else if result.contains("int(") {
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "int(", with: "")
            result.removeLast(1)

        } else if result.contains("bool(") {
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "bool(", with: "")
            result.removeLast(1)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

How to fix this issue with Swift codable?

Comment: Please add JSON that you are using which coming from server.

Comment: Use [this](http://www.jsoncafe.com/) to create perfect model class

Comment: Your code is too complicated. Just decode `Type` as `[String:String]`

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this Gist I have created for parsing dynamic key based JSON via `Decodable`.
https://gist.github.com/aksswami/f30007b71fe78a6d99fff583b38cc480

You can also go through this extensive resource for more Codable basics.
https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/